# Timing of nested loops output

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I just started with JavaScript and I am trying to write a small open source application for fingerboard training. I nested some time loops to account for the intervals between *hangtime* and breaks:

```
<html>

<body>
  Sets: <input type="number" id="setsIN" value="5">
  <br>
  Rounds: <input type="number" id="roundsIN" value="6">
  <br>
  Workout: <input type="number" id="hangIN" value="7">
  <br>
  Short Break: <input type="number" id="shortbreakIN" value="3">
  <br>
  Long Break: <input type="number" id="longbreakIN" value="180">
  <br>

  <hr>

  <script>
    // Import values
    var setsNUMBER = parseInt(document.getElementById("setsIN").value);
    var roundsNUMBER = parseInt(document.getElementById("roundsIN").value);
    var hangTIME = parseInt(document.getElementById("hangIN").value);
    var shortbreakTIME = parseInt(document.getElementById("shortbreakIN").value);
    var longbreakTIME = parseInt(document.getElementById("longbreakIN").value);
    console.log("Sets: " + setsNUMBER)
    console.log("Rounds: " + roundsNUMBER)
    console.log("Hang: " + hangTIME)
    console.log("Short breaks: " + shortbreakTIME)
    console.log("Long breaks: " + longbreakTIME)
    // calculate duration
    var duration = ((hangTIME + shortbreakTIME) * roundsNUMBER + longbreakTIME) * setsNUMBER
    console.log("Duration (minutes): " + duration/60)
    // Counter
    var setsCOUNT = 1; // Start counting at 1
    var roundsCOUNT = 1; // Start counting at 1
    var hangCOUNT = 1; // Start counting at 1
    var shortbreakCOUNT = 1; // Start counting at 1
    var longbreakCOUNT = 1; // Start counting at 1
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Sets
  while (setsCOUNT < setsNUMBER+1) {
    console.log("Set: "+ setsCOUNT)
    setsCOUNT++;
    roundsCOUNT = 1;
    longbreakCOUNT = 1;
    // Rounds
      while (roundsCOUNT  < roundsNUMBER+1) {
        console.log("Round: "+ roundsCOUNT)
        roundsCOUNT++;
        hangCOUNT = 1;
        shortbreakCOUNT = 1;
        // HAngtime
          while (hangCOUNT  < hangTIME+1) {
            console.log("WorkOutTime: "+ hangCOUNT)
            hangCOUNT++;
          }
        // Pausetime
         while (shortbreakCOUNT  < shortbreakTIME+1) {
           console.log("ShortBreak: "+ shortbreakCOUNT)
           shortbreakCOUNT++;
         }
          }
          // LongBreak
           while (longbreakCOUNT  < longbreakTIME+1) {
             //console.log("longBreak: "+ longbreakCOUNT)
             longbreakCOUNT++;
      }
  }

  </script>

</html>
```

The sequence of the training is as follows:
- 7 seconds workout
- 3 seconds break
Repeat the above six times (=60 seconds)
Rest for 180 seconds
Repeat all steps above five times (=5*4 minutes)

It seems like I got the sequence of the output right. The `console.log()` is returned in the right order. Currently however, whenever I run the script all log lines are returned immediately right after I load the page. How can I print one line every second? I experimentd with `setTimeout()` but couldn't get it running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops should not be used to organize time. Loop is a series of operations happening in *no time*, one after another.

What I would do is to use some time function: either `setTimeout`* or `requestAnimationFrame`, albeit in the latter you will have to track time in each frame yourself. Doable and probably more reliable* but for the sake of example I used `setTimeout`. It’s proof of concept, anyway.

What you want to do is:

- Start set, and call Start round or Finish
- Start round, and call Start Workout or Start the next set
- Repeat 6 times:

  - Work out, and 7 seconds later call Short break or Long break
  - Take a short break, and 3 seconds later call Work out
- Take a long break, and 180 seconds later call Start set

This is series of steps that are called in x amount of times (except for new set and new round, which are just data updates) with certain pauses in between.

### Code

To not come empty handed, this is working proof of concept:

```html
<html>
<body>
  Sets: <input type="number" id="setsIN" value="5">
  <br>
  Rounds: <input type="number" id="roundsIN" value="6">
  <br>
  Workout: <input type="number" id="hangIN" value="7">
  <br>
  Short Break: <input type="number" id="shortbreakIN" value="3">
  <br>
  Long Break: <input type="number" id="longbreakIN" value="180">
  <br>

  <hr>

  <script>
    const setsNUMBER = 'setsNUMBER';
    const roundsNUMBER = 'roundsNUMBER';
    const hangNUMBER = 'hangNUMBER';
    const hangTIME = 'hangTIME';
    const shortbreakTIME = 'shortbreakTIME';
    const longbreakTIME = 'longbreakTIME';

    const setsCOUNT = 'setsCOUNT';
    const roundsCOUNT = 'roundsCOUNT';
    const hangCOUNT = 'hangCOUNT';
    const shortbreakCOUNT = 'shortbreakCOUNT';
    const longbreakCOUNT = 'longbreakCOUNT';

    function training({ config, data, next: current }) {
        switch (current) {
            case setsCOUNT: {
                if (data[setsCOUNT] < config[setsNUMBER]) {
                    const updatedSetsCOUNT = data[setsCOUNT] + 1;
                    console.log(`Set: ${updatedSetsCOUNT}`);

                    training({
                        config,
                        data: {
                            ...data,
                            [setsCOUNT]: updatedSetsCOUNT,
                            [roundsCOUNT]: 0,
                        },
                        next: roundsCOUNT,
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('The end. It was a good workout, bro!');
                }
                break;
            }

            case roundsCOUNT: {
                if (data.roundsCOUNT < config.roundsNUMBER) {
                    const updatedRoundsCOUNT = data.roundsCOUNT + 1;
                    console.log(`Round: ${updatedRoundsCOUNT}`);

                    training({
                        config,
                        data: {
                            ...data,
                            [roundsCOUNT]: updatedRoundsCOUNT,
                            [hangCOUNT]: 0,
                            [shortbreakCOUNT]: 0,
                        },
                        next: hangCOUNT,
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('New set');

                    training({
                        config,
                        data: {
                            ...data,
                            roundsCOUNT: 0,
                        },
                        next: setsCOUNT,
                    });
                }
                break;
            }

            case hangCOUNT: {
                if (data[hangCOUNT] < config[hangNUMBER]) {
                    const updatedHangCOUNT = data[hangCOUNT] + 1;
                    console.log(`WorkOutTime: ${updatedHangCOUNT}`);

                    setTimeout(training, config[hangTIME] * 1000, {
                        config,
                        data: {
                            ...data,
                            [hangCOUNT]: updatedHangCOUNT,
                        },
                        next: shortbreakTIME,
                    });
                } else {
                    training({
                        config,
                        data,
                        next: longbreakCOUNT,
                    });
                }
                break;
            }

            case shortbreakTIME: {
                const updatedShortBreakCOUNT = data[shortbreakCOUNT] + 1;
                console.log(`Short break: ${updatedShortBreakCOUNT}`);

                setTimeout(training, config[shortbreakTIME] * 1000, {
                    config,
                    data: {
                        ...data,
                        [shortbreakCOUNT]: updatedShortBreakCOUNT,
                    },
                    next: hangCOUNT,
                });
                break;
            }

            case longbreakCOUNT: {
                // this update is probably obsolete as setsCOUNT stage is keeping track
                const updatedLongbreakCOUNT = data[longbreakCOUNT] + 1;
                console.log(`LongBreak: ${updatedLongbreakCOUNT}`);

                setTimeout(training, config[longbreakTIME] * 1000, {
                    config,
                    data: {
                        ...data,
                        [longbreakCOUNT]: updatedLongbreakCOUNT,
                    },
                    next: roundsCOUNT,
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    const config = {
        [setsNUMBER]: parseInt(document.getElementById("setsIN").value),
        [roundsNUMBER]: parseInt(document.getElementById("roundsIN").value),
        [hangNUMBER]: 6,
        [hangTIME]: parseInt(document.getElementById("hangIN").value),
        [shortbreakTIME]: parseInt(document.getElementById("shortbreakIN").value),
        [longbreakTIME]: parseInt(document.getElementById("longbreakIN").value),
    };

    console.log("Sets: " + config.setsNUMBER);
    console.log("Rounds: " + config.roundsNUMBER);
    console.log("Workout time: " + config.hangTIME);
    console.log("Short break time: " + config.shortbreakTIME);
    console.log("Long break time: " + config.longbreakTIME);
    console.log("Duration (minutes): " + (
        (
            (
                (config.hangTIME + config.shortbreakTIME)
                * config.roundsNUMBER
                + config.longbreakTIME
            )
            * config.setsNUMBER
        )
        / 60)
    );

    const data = {
        [setsCOUNT]: 0,
        [roundsCOUNT]: 0,
        [hangCOUNT]: 0,
        [shortbreakCOUNT]: 0,
        [longbreakCOUNT]: 0,
    };

    training({ config, data, next: setsCOUNT });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

General concept is function `training` that takes arbitrary object with config, data, and next step, and calls itself again with new values until condition is met (in this case number of sets finished).

I recommend against using it as delivered.

1. I would split it into small functions.
2. If after short break comes long break then probably such short break can be skipped.
3. Function above sometimes mutates object. This is unlikely to cause problems but maybe creating new objects when passing would be safer. Up to you.

[**Edit**] Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hmcwf0p5/1/

### [Edit] Code 2

Then, I was asked if the code above can display seconds as they go. (This is a very good example why specs should be clear from the beginning; otherwise, it can result in very different implementations.)

In short, no.

In long, we could but due to nature of `setTimeout` this could not be accurate. I don’t even wanna go. Hence, I started thinking on different approach and came up with timeline.

#### Code: timeline

Idea: run timed function that does something in given interval. In our case this will be 1 second. Then, depending on our data, we should do something.

```
const prepareTimeline = (possibleTimeline) => {
    const sortedFrames = Object.keys(possibleTimeline)
        .map(Number)
        .filter((number) => !Number.isNaN(number))
        .sort((a, b) => a - b);

    return Object.assign(
        sortedFrames.reduce(
            (acc, number) => Object.assign(acc, { [number]: possibleTimeline[number] }),
            {}
        ),
        { last: Math.max(...sortedFrames) + 1 }
    );
}

const handleFrame = (data) => {
    const { second, frames, frames: { last }, timelineId } = data;

    if (second == last) {
        return clearInterval(timelineId);
    }

    if (frames[second]) {
        frames[second].forEach((message) => {
            console.log(message);
        });
    }

    data.second = second + 1;
};

const runTimeline = (frames) => {
    const timelineObject = {
        second: 0,
        frames: prepareTimeline(frames),
        timelineId: null,
    }

    const timelineId = setInterval(handleFrame, 1000, timelineObject);
    timelineObject.timelineId = timelineId;
}
```

What happens:

1. `runTimeline` takes an object with frames. The key is second at which something’s gonna happen and the value is array with messages to be displayed.
2. Inside `prepareTimeline` function removes all the non-numeric keys (passed as `frames` property) and adds `last` which is the biggest value plus 1 second, so we can kill `setInterval`.
3. `handleFrame` is a function called each second. As param it takes object with `timelineId` (which we can pass to `clearInterval`), `frames`, `second`. Inside this function we mutate this object.

   - Here you can decide what you wanna do with your frame. Instead of console.logging it, you can setState of your app or whatever you find fit.
   - Also, in my example it’s object of arrays but it’s up to `handleFrame` what is accepted.

Notation `setInterval(functionName, time, ...params)` will call `functionName(...params)` every second.

Now, let’s run it:

```
runTimeline({
    1: ['Initial message'],
    5: ['Second message', 'And last'],
});
```

In console log, after 1 second first shows message

```
Initial message
```

Then 4 seconds later (at the same time):

```
Second message
And last
```

#### Workout timeline

So what’s left is to build workout frames. `buildWorkoutTimeline` takes params and runs *a lot* of nested loops (which was somewhat initial implementation). Probably could be written differently but I’ll leave it to you.

```
const buildWorkoutTimeline = ({
    sets = 3,
    rounds = 5,
    workouts = 6,
    workoutTime = 7,
    pauseTime = 3,
    restTime = 180,
} = {}) => {
    let seconds = 0;
    const workoutTimeline = { [seconds]: [] };

    for (let set = 1; set <= sets; set++) {
        workoutTimeline[seconds].push(`New set: ${set}`);
        for (let round = 1; round <= rounds; round++) {
            workoutTimeline[seconds].push(`Set ${set}’s new round: ${round}`);
            for (let workout = 1; workout <= workouts; workout++) {
                seconds += 1;
                workoutTimeline[seconds] = [`Set ${set}, round ${round}’s new workout: ${workout}`];
                for (let time = 0; time < workoutTime; time++) {
                    seconds += 1;
                    workoutTimeline[seconds] = [`Seconds: ${workoutTime - time}`];
                }

                if (workout < workouts) {
                    seconds += 1;
                    workoutTimeline[seconds] = ['Short break'];
                    for (let time = 0; time < pauseTime; time++) {
                        seconds += 1;
                        workoutTimeline[seconds] = [`Seconds: ${pauseTime - time}`];
                    }
                } else if (round < rounds) {
                    seconds += 1;
                    workoutTimeline[seconds] = ['Long break'];
                    for (let time = 0; time < restTime; time++) {
                        seconds += 1;
                        workoutTimeline[seconds] = [`Seconds: ${restTime - time}`];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    seconds += 1;
    workoutTimeline[seconds] = [
        'Workout finished',
        `Total time: ${(seconds / 60) | 0} minutes, ${seconds % 60} seconds`
    ];

    return workoutTimeline;
};

runTimeline(buildWorkoutTimeline());
```

Ta-dam.

---

* `setTimeout(someFunction, 1000)` will not execute 1000 milliseconds from the moment it was called but **not earlier than** 1000 milliseconds. So total workout might be slightly longer. `requestAnimationFrame` could give better results. Test it.

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you very much for your effort! ... much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. Using loops for that is pretty common in the beginning. Later I was thinking that maybe `for-await..of` with async generator could be used to write it in loop manner (under the hood those would be still Promises). But I never tried that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: Is there a way to print the seconds for each "step"? Are you climbing by any chance? I'll send you a link once I am finished. I also plan to make the code public on GitHub.

Comment: Like, "1 second", "2 seconds", "3 seconds" etc.?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Eventually, I want to display a counter for each step 8)

Comment: In that case the solution above might not be what you're looking for. Something revolving around `setInterval`/`requestAnimationFrame` with tracking how many seconds have passed could be wiser choice.

Comment: @Jonas, I added another approach. This will allow you to handle each second of your workout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196732/discussion-between-the-witness-and-jonas).